# Windows 11 home on a new laptop can't ping wifi router and other machines on the same wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ping

I have the issue only with one machine: I have an 8550u laptop, a 5800x desktop, then a new 12700H laptop.

The issue is only with the 12700H laptop: from this laptop, I can't ping the wifi router at address 192.168.3.1, and can't ping the 8550u laptop and 5800x desktop which are on the same wifi network.

From the 8550u laptop and 5800x desktop, I also can't ping the 12700H laptop, but these 2 can ping each other, plus the wifi router.

So not sure why the 12700H is so special, this is a new laptop, I didn't do any specific firewall settings on it.

Comment: Make sure Wireless is Private and not Public.  I connect my Windows 11 machines and so have Network Discovery ON.  I suggest you try both these things. I did not have to adjust firewall.

Comment: I just did a test, found now I can ping the new laptop from the desktop machine, and can talk to the VMs running on the laptop, the VMs on the new laptop can also talk to VMs on the desktop, but still can't ping wifi gateway.

Comment: but still can't ping wifi gateway   ... What does this mean?  It sounds like your issues is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the laptop is running Windows, then by default ping is disabled

> If you have a firewall enabled in Windows, ping requests are blocked by default.

[Configure the Windows firewall to allow pings link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aopy)

> When Windows Firewall is enabled with default settings, you can’t use the ping command from another device to see if your PC is alive.

[How to Allow Pings](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/allow-pings-icmp-echo-request-through-your-windows-vista-firewall/amp/)